# How to allow a normal PBS user to run jobs under a different name

Tags: jenkins, batch-processing, pbs, qsub

I have a Jenkins project which is submitting jobs to a PBS Pro batch system. In Jenkins, within the "Build" section, I execute a shell command which simply submits a job script using `qsub job.sh`. However, the job is being run as user `jenkins` (as reported by `qstat`), which is the default user for Jenkins. This is not what I want.

Instead, I want to be able to execute the Job as a different user using `qsub -u anotherUser job.sh`, but this fails with a message `qsub: Bad UID for job execution`.

So my question is: How can I allow user `jenkins` to run the job as a different user without `jenkins` being a PBS manager, operator or root? Everything is working on the same machine, so I guess that I don't need a `/etc/hosts.equiv` file as suggested [in this serverfault post](https://serverfault.com/a/857532/408391), for example.

This is actually not a Jenkins question, yet I added the Jenkins tag since other Jenkins users may face similar issues and maybe there is a built-in option I am not aware of.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @jiminy_crist: unfortunately not - but maybe it helps to have the other user be in the same group as the Jenkins user? That's just a shot in the dark, dealing with Jenkins has been a while for me.

Comment: I managed to get things working today by having all users that should allow the admin account to submit jobs for them add the admin account to their `~/.rhosts` file, but I'm not sure if that's the best way. Asked on the PBS discourse to see if they have any suggestions: http://community.pbspro.org/t/submit-job-as-different-user/1630

Comment: @jimini_crist maybe you can post it as an answer as soon as you have something working, who knows who else will encounter the same problem in the future... :-)